# calling python script from another fails at class definition

Tags: python, exec

I have a script called `insertPrintCode.py`, which works on its own.
I want to call this from another python script using

```
def main():
    execfile("insertPrintCode.py")

def execfile(filename):
    exec(compile(open(filename).read(), filename, 'exec'))
```

This fails inside `insertPrintCode.py` at the first use of

```
newSearch = FileSearch()
```

with

> NameError: global name 'FileSearch' is not defined

FileSearch is a class defined inside the same file.

Comment: First, why are you defining your own `execfile` instead of using [the builtin of the same name](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile)? And why are you explicitly calling `compile` instead of just `exec`ing the source code?

Comment: Second, why are you using `execfile` in the first place instead of just `import insertPrintCode` (or `from insertPrintCode import *`) or running it in a subprocess? There are some cases where `exec` is what you want, but they're not that common, and if you don't immediately have a rock-solid answer, yours probably isn't one of them.

Comment: Third, you need to give us the code for `insertPrintCode.py` (or, better, a stripped-down [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) if you want us to debug your problem, instead of making us guess at what you might have done wrong.

Comment: Does `insertPrintCode.py` run on its own, if you execute it directly on the commandline?

Comment: The file does run on its own. It was designed that way. `execfile` is not available in Python 3.x, I used it as an abbrevitation. I could as well name it different. Using `import` does not make much sence if the file has no function to call. I could place all the code into a `main()` and load that with input, but that is only a workaround.